# Changing typing behavior of ListBox

Tags: vb.net, winforms, listbox

When typing into a listbox the listbox scrolls to the next item with first letter matching the input character. I want to disable/change this behavior.

I implemented a handler for the keypress event and implemented my new behavior, but I don't see any way to remove the old behavior.

How can I disable the default behavior?

Here is the event handler for the keypress event:

```vb
    Private Sub FooListBox_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles FooListBox.KeyPress

        If SearchResetTimer.Enabled Then
            SearchResetTimer.Stop()
            SearchTimer.Stop()

        Else
            BeginUpdate()

            SearchedString = ""
        End If

        SearchedString = SearchedString & e.KeyChar

        SearchResetTimer.Start()
        SearchTimer.Start()
    End Sub

    Private Function SearchFor(listbox As ListBox, target As String) As Integer
        For i As Integer = listbox.SelectedIndex To listbox.Items.Count - 1
            If listbox.Items(i).ToString().ToLower().StartsWith(target) Then
                Return i
            End If
        Next

        For i As Integer = 0 To listbox.SelectedIndex - 1
            If listbox.Items(i).ToString().ToLower().StartsWith(target) Then
                Return i
            End If
        Next

        Return -1
    End Function

    Private Sub SearchTimer_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SearchTimer.Tick
        SearchTimer.Stop()

        Dim Found As Integer = SearchFor(FooListBox, SearchedString)

        If Found <> -1 Then
            FooListBox.SelectedIndex = Found
        End If

        EndUpdate()
    End Sub

    Private Sub SearchResetTimer_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SearchResetTimer.Tick
        SearchResetTimer.Stop()
    End Sub
```

Quick overview: there are two timers, searchTimer that when ticked searches for the string and updates the control, searchResetTimer which resets the searched string and marks the beginning of a new user input.

<sub>Note that I am not releasing this code under CC, it is for illustration purposes only</sub>

Comment: Add to the question an example of the code you tried to do but it doesn't work, then we can help you.

Comment: @Gander What example code should I include? I'm asking how to disable the default value. I do not see any listed properties that would be relevant. I can include my handler for the keypress event if that would be helpful?

Comment: This one: `I implemented a handler for the keypress event`

Comment: @Gander I'm not sure it will really help, since like I said the problem is disabling the built in behavior

Comment: Now you have a better chance that someone will help you. I do not know this language, but if you say that you are programming but it does not work for you, the best way is to show what you are programming and how, and then someone who knows this will focus on the code and not on extracting information from you.

Comment: I believe that this action has brought you closer to solving the problem.

Comment: @Gander I don't think it's a programming error, it's a question about the API.

Comment: How do you type into a ListBox? Are you talking about a ComboBox?

Comment: The comments [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59313953/change-selection-in-checkedlistbox-as-user-types) should help. Don't forget to `e.SuppressKeyPress = true` as the first line in the `KeyPress` event.

Comment: I've converted the comment that @JQSOFT mentioned in an answer, so you can test the code. Give it a look, there's the chance that it's the same thing you need.

Comment: @JQSOFT I will try this Monday when I get a chance, thanks

Comment: @Mary If the ListBox has focus, then typing a character will bring an entry which starts with that character into view.

Comment: @AndrewMorton Well, I'll be darned. Learn several new things a day on SO.